# Publishing an Android App with Different Package Names on Google Play and an Alternative Store

Tags: android, google-play, android-room, package-name

I have encountered a challenge while trying to publish my Android application on both Google Play and an alternative app store, Rustor. Here's the situation:

My Android application originally had the package name "com.example.project" and I successfully published it on Rustore using this package name.

However, when attempting to publish the same application on Google Play, I ran into an issue. Google Play does not allow applications with package names starting with "com.example."

My goal is to have the application recognized as the same on both Google Play and Rustor so that users can update it seamlessly without losing application data, including the Room database, regardless of the platform they initially downloaded it from. Additionally, I need to maintain the package name on Rustor while simultaneously creating the same app with a different package name on Google Play.

I kindly request your assistance on how to address this situation and unify the application across both platforms while complying with the package name restrictions of Google Play. Any insights, suggestions, or recommendations on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Consider using different application id package name for each store with same code base: [How to use different package names between flavors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39552590/295004)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The package name once chosen is fix and can not be changed. The only thing you can do is providing an easy way to migrate from one app version to the other. The simplest way would be using the sharedUid system. Alternatively a signature protected content provider could also be used to allow data exchange between your two app versions.